# Javascript / Jquery, disabling all double clicks anywhere within body of web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, double-click

I already have a lot of AJAX code written for a web app and didn't take into account the problems that double clicks on some things can cause. I already implemented an "inprogress" variable for sensitive AJAX calls so that it won't be messed up by double clicking by the user but I am wondering if there is a simple way to just disable all double clicks anywhere (in any element) within the entire body of the web page rather than having to do it individually for each specific element.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: did you actually mean 'double-clicking' in the meaning of two clicks w/ almost no pause between them, or clicking 2+ times on a button that is wired to an ajax call and thus would add another call on top of the old on, and so on....?

Comment: I mean double clicking like when you have to double click something on a windows desktop icon to open an application / file. While I don't do it myself, some of our users have problems with this action being ingrained in them so they double click everything on the web app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something crazy like this:

```
$("*").dblclick(function (event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

In theory, it would capture the double-click event on any element and then basically do nothing (cancels the default action).

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working, not quite sure why as I put it in the `$(document).ready(function() { }` has anyone verified that this does work for them?

Comment: I put in alert so that it will now tell me when a double click is performed and thats working but the part of actually canceling the second click doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: I honestly don't know what you're trying to keep the user from doing. Double-clicking a link? Why? I just posted this because it **should** do what you're asking but you have to realize that the browser is likely also listening for clicks and may choose to do something you have no control over.

Comment: yeah prevent them from double clicking a link basically, its because if they do it twice it messes up the AJAX return the way the app is currently coded (such as loading the ajax return twice into the div)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('*').dblclick(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); return false; });
```

Should handle it, however there is probably a better solution out there.

Comment: What is benefit of returning false?

Comment: @Mohsen it performs a similar task to preventDefault() in a normal javascript event handler. I usually do it as well in case there is a compatibility issue between preventDefault() and the browser. Though I don't know if that case actually ever happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you havn't bound events to double click, double click will do nothing. It is event of its own.
Click and DoubleClick are different events.

Comment: I haven't bound for the most part, I have used onclick for a lot of things so that definitely does take in both clicks and causes issues, I wanted to make the app as server-side heavy as possible so I did that for ease in reading the code as I am not a big javascripter